# Mouseover and mouseout colour change of text

Tags: css

I need to colour change the text when mouse over it and mouse moved away from it. So, I got only the mouse over for css, is this correct way to do that? and what is the code for change colour on mouseout for css? from following code the text changes to green, but stays green even after mouseout.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .mouseover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: green;

}
  </style>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can use the :hover pseudo-class like this:

```
<span class="sometexttohover">This is text to hover over</span>

<style type="text/css">

.sometexttohover {
color: #000;
}

.sometexttohover:hover {
color: #567843;
}

</style>
```

Comment: @VikingBlooded: I tried this code this doesn't work, and there is a main css file which controls "a" , I cant change it there, because, it will affect the whole page. I need a unique css style for this particular text to change color.

Comment: This was just an example, you can use it on any pseudo element or class. You could do .thisismyhovertext:hover and apply that class to your elements if you want to.